# A search for '0' returns results

Tags: loop, search

I have a a CPT set up with a custom taxonomy attached to it. I recently noticed that if I search for `0` (zero), in the back-end as well as the front-end, it gives me results. None of these resultant posts have `0` anywhere in the title as well as the content. I have not modified the loop in anyway, it is just the plain search template. This makes me wonder about 2 things:

1. What does WP search through by default?
2. Is there a way to stop it from searching for `0`?

Any ideas?

***Update:***

From the comments below, I am updating my requirement:

**Is there a way to search for the posts which contain `0` in either the title or the content, when `0` is entered as the search key?**

Comment: I've just tested in a blank theme with dummy data, search with `0` (zero) fired an empty search - that means `all`: `SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS  wp_posts.ID FROM wp_posts  WHERE 1=1  AND wp_posts.post_type IN ('post', 'page', 'attachment') AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish')  ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC LIMIT 0, 10`

Comment: So it will give me all the content? Any way to stop it?

Comment: The fact that `wp-includes/query.php` contains condition:
`if(!empty($q['s'])){$search = $this->parse_search($q);}`. When your `?s=0` this conditions not `true` and stop using a `parse_search`. A `parse_search` function generates `LIKE` string in addition to a general query. Considering above, when `?s=0`-> you does not have `LIKE` part of the query provided by `parse_search` and, as @Mayeenul Islam mentioned - "all" returned.

Comment: Thanks both of you. Please add an answer and I will accept it. I think I'll provide some other way to avoid this from happening.

Comment: I think as long as we are not getting an answer regarding **Is there a way to stop it from searching for 0?** we should look for a perfect answer.

Comment: Yes. You're right!

Comment: Hold on do the goal is to stop searching for "0" or allow search for "0"?

Comment: @IgnatB. In my opinion, `0` should return no posts :-)

Comment: @Pieter Goosen, agree, but it depends on site and search functionality purpose. Updated answer with solution how to prevent "0" from being searched.

Comment: It should return only those posts which have `0` in either the title or the content. Updated my question details.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Considering @Mayeenul Islam comment:

> I've just tested in a blank theme with dummy data, search with 0
>   (zero) fired an empty search - that means all:
>
> `SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_posts.ID
>   FROM wp_posts  WHERE 1=1  AND
>   wp_posts.post_type IN ('post', 'page', 'attachment') AND
>   (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish')  ORDER BY wp_posts.post_date DESC
>   LIMIT 0, 10`

and the fact that `wp-includes/query.php` contains

```
if ( ! empty( $q['s'] ) ) {
    $search = $this->parse_search( $q );
}
```

, we can see that `!empty($q['s'])`, where `$q['s'] == 0 (or "0")` will return `FALSE`. This means that search query wont have `LIKE` part, when `$q['s'] == 0` and it return "all" posts since nothing restrict query with specific conditions, that should be inside `LIKE` part.

This is confirmed by [`empty()`](http://nz.php.net/manual/en/function.empty.php) function documentation:

> The following things are considered to be empty:
>
> ...
>
> - 0 (0 as an integer)
> - "0" (0 as a string)
>
> ...

Due to that we're not able to filter/update, "0" in order to pass if-empty conditional logic. What I suggest is a query updates in case if users are going to search for "0".

Here is a quickfix how to allow users to search for "0".

```
add_filter("posts_where", "search_hotfix", 10, 1);
function search_hotfix($where_clause){

    if(get_query_var('s') == 0){
      $where_clause .=  " AND (((wp_posts.post_title LIKE '%0%') OR (wp_posts.post_content LIKE '%0%'))) ";
    }

    return $where_clause; 
}
```

---

**UPDATE**:

And here is a quickfix how to stop WP search for "0". This code will force WP_Query to provide no results.

```
add_action('pre_get_posts', 'search_hotfix_reset_q');
function search_hotfix_reset_q($query){
    if ( get_query_var('s') == 0) {
        $query->query_vars['post__in'] = array(0);
    }
}
```

Comment: IIRC, if you pass an empty array to `post__in`, `WP_Query` will return all posts regardless.

Comment: Recently tested on WP 4.3 twentyfifteen the `array(0)` solution - works. `array()` - yep, all posts. The fact that there are no post with `ID=0` in WP installantion usually ;)

Comment: I have updated my question details. How about only searching the posts which have a `0` in either the title or the content when `0` is the search key?

Comment: @Rutwick Gangurde the code  with `add_filter("posts_where", "search_hotfix", 10, 1);` is a hotfix that allow users to search for "0" in title and content

Comment: Thanks a lot Ignat and Pieter! This has been quite a learning.

Comment: @RutwickGangurde note that this approach can affect other queries too on the page, so you need to restrict it further, e.g. to the main query.

Comment: @birgire Thanks for pointing that out. Since I know the cause and the basic solution for it, I can play around with the code to make it better!